# GROUP BY date and empty data

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have table `hits` with columns `created` and `user_id`.

I want get stats `hits count` for last 30 days, **GROUP BY** `day`. But I have problem, because some days user dont have traffic.

And as a result, I do not see this day in the report.

How to get data for every day (with 0 hits), even where there is no hits?

My query:

```
SELECT user_id, toDate(created) as date, COUNT() as count
FROM hits
WHERE created > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
GROUP BY toDate(created), user_id
```

Comment: https://learnsql.com/blog/null-values-group-clause/

Comment: What mysql version? If mysql8, you can use CTE to generate rows for every day.

Comment: my database `clickhouse`

Comment: order by with fill https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclickhouse%5DORDER+BY+WITH+FILL